# Backbone.js: _.bindAll() in initialize - why is this used?

Tags: backbone.js

I've been looking at some examples of backbone.js based application.  I notice that in some (such as [this example](http://andyet.net/blog/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/) below) the underscore function `_.bindAll()` is used:

```
 initialize: function (args) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'changeTitle');
        this.model.bind('change:title', this.changeTitle);
    },
```

whereas in others (such as the [todo app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) below) do not:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
  this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
},
```

What is the purpose of `_.bindAll()` in this context, and is it necessary?

Comment: Using `_.bindAll` is bad practice because if you delete method and forget to edit your `_.bindAll` all will crash, also some times you need scope different from binded

Comment: But in backbone 0.3.x you can't set context in event binding so using `_.bindAll` was popular

Comment: @ant_Ti "was popular" are you saying that with > 0.3.x we no longer need to do this? That's how it seems to me, so just making sure. Thanks!

Comment: @ant_Ti Just because it crashes when you use it incorrectly does not make it a bad practice. That makes it a friendly function, that throws you errors when you use it incorrectly. As the answer below by @sciyoshi says, it allows you to refer to `this` more easily.

Comment: @nackjicholson ease of support and reusability are better than ease of use. There are a lot of gotchas with `_.bindAll`.

Comment: isn't this replaced by listenTo now?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`_.bindAll()` changes `this` in the named functions to always point to that object, so that you can use `this.model.bind()`. Notice that in your second example, a third argument is passed to `bind()`; that's why using `_.bindAll()` isn't necessary in that case. In general, it's a good idea to use for any methods on the model that will be used as callbacks to events so that you can refer to `this` more easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
In Detail: _.bind(ctx, 'method')
```

Takes your method, creates a copy with the context bound to 'ctx' and adds the copy as property.

This is a workaround for `jQuery.bind()` not allowing you to pass in a context.
JQ will always call the callbacks with a undefined context. Backbone is built on jQuery.

See here: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this