# Undefined method in Backbone

Tags: javascript, methods, backbone.js

I am trying to use `this.moveCursor` with Backbone, but it says it is **undefined** when I `console.log`.  The method is obviously defined so I am not sure what is wrong here.

At first I though it was because of `this.` and the `switch` statement not returning.

However, even when I `console.log` outside the `switch` statement, it the same.

Can anyone help?

```
setup: function(){      
        $(document).on('keydown', this.keyCode);
},

keyCode: function(e){
                switch(e.keyCode) {
                    case 37:  console.log(this.moveCursor(-1,0)); break; //undefined
                    case 38:  return this.moveCursor(0,-1); break;
                    case 39:  return this.moveCursor(1,0); break;
                    case 40:  return this.moveCursor(0,1); break;
                    case 32:  return play.selectBlock(); break;
                    case 13:  return play.selectBlock(); break;
                };

        console.log(this.moveCursor()); //undefined
            }, 



   moveCursor: function(x, y){
                    var cursorSelected = play.get('cursorSelected'),
                        cursorX = play.get('cursorX'),
                        cursorY = play.get('cursorY');



                console.log('moveCursor');

                if(cursorSelected){
                    x += cursorX;
                    y += cursorY;

                    this.getBlock(x,y);
                } else {
                    //
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *context issue*. The `this` keyword will represent the *caller* of the `keyCode()` function, no matter where the `keyCode()` has been defined into.

To know more about this try to `console.log( this )`, it will show you what it really `this` in that moment of the execution.

To solve this issue you can play with [_.bindAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366664/backbone-js-bindall-in-initialize-why-is-this-used).

If the `keyCode()` is a handler of a `Backbone.View.events` the binding should be already done.

#### Update

I see the `keyCode()` is a handler of a normal jQuery event:

```
$(document).on( 'keydown', this.keyCode );
```

The `_.bindAll()` will work for it, also you can use a [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) like this:

```
$(document).on( 'keydown', $.proxy( this.keyCode, this ) );
```

Comment: I am getting undefined within the `moveCursor` function under the `if` statments `this.getBlock` and `this.setCursor`.  Is it possible for the two `_.bindAll` statements?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with _"Is it possible for the two _.bindAll statements?"_

Comment: sorry, i figured out the problem. it has nothing to do with this.